# Implementing a generic interface in Go

Tags: go, generics, interface

In the below example, `WK8Map` implements `OrderedMap`:

```golang
type OrderedMap interface {
    Get(string) string
}

type WK8Map struct {
    value *orderedmap.OrderedMap[string, string]
}

func (m *WK8Map) Get(key string) string {
    return ""
}
```

However, the moment I introduce generics, my IDE GoLand says that `WK8Map` no longer implements `OrderedMap`:

```golang
type OrderedMap[K comparable, V any] interface {
    Get(K) V
}

type WK8Map[K comparable, V any] struct {
    value *orderedmap.OrderedMap[K, V]
}

func (m *WK8Map[K, V]) Get(key K) V {
    value, _ := m.value.Get(key)
    return value
}
```

Why does my attempt at implementing the generic interface fail?

Comment: Go has no (real) co/contravariance and absolutely no inheritance. OrderMap requires Get(string)string. WK8Map has no method. *WK8Map has Get(K)V.

Comment: I meant to write "Why does my attempt at implementing the generic interface fail?", not "Why does my attempt at generic inheritance fail?"

Comment: Please add a bigger example of how you use `WK8Map` as `OrderedMap`. Still the compiler is correct: `WK8Map` does'n implement `OrderedMap` interface since methods with the pointer receiver (i.e. `func (t *T)`) do not belong to the method set of `T`. It is `*WK8Map` who implements the interface.

Comment: Have a look: https://go.dev/play/p/0cj_vShQnIP. The value of type `&WK8Map` is assignable to `OrderedMap`, but not the value of type `WK8Map`